# Firebase Phone number authentication error, Phone number not readable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I enter a phone number into my EditText field and press login, the java code has to validate if the editText field is empty or not. So after entering my phone no., the ***if(!phonenumber.isempty())*** is always false and the else statement is executed, that is "Please enter number" Toast

Here is my compelete code:

```
public class User_login extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editTextphone;
    private Button otp_login;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_login);

        otp_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.otp_login);
        editTextphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextphone);
        String phoneNumber = editTextphone.getText().toString().trim();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        otp_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!phoneNumber.isEmpty()){
                    if(phoneNumber.length() == 10){

                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        otp_login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    
                        PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                                .setPhoneNumber("+91" + phoneNumber)
                                .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .setActivity(User_login.this)
                            
                                .build();
                        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
                        new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                otp_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull FirebaseException e) {

                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                otp_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(User_login.this,"Some error occured" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull String s, @NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),opt_verify.class);
                                intent.putExtra("phone", editTextphone.getText().toString());
                                intent.putExtra("mVerificationId", s);

                                startActivity(intent);


                            }
                        };
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(User_login.this,"Please enter complete number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(User_login.this,"Please enter mobile number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, home_user.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the EditText input in the onClick Listner, only then you could get the latest inputted value from the edittext.

ie,

```
String phoneNumber = editTextphone.getText().toString().trim();
```

should be called inside :

```
otp_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String phoneNumber = editTextphone.getText().toString().trim(); //like this
                if(!phoneNumber.isEmpty()){
```

Comment: Tried this, still the same error, "enter phone no"

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your logic. The reason is that you are getting text before clicking the button meanwhile when the onCreate method runs it gets the value form the EditText. But you need get the value when you click the button each time.
Try this code:

```
otp_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String phoneNumber = editTextphone.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!phoneNumber.isEmpty()) {
        if (phoneNumber.length() == 10) {
            //you logic or code here
        }
    }
  }
}
```